# Windows 8: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-8.1, android-sdk-2.3, android-virtual-device

For the past few days I have been trying to get my Android AVD emulator (from the SDK) working, but none of the solutions posted previously have worked for me. I am running Windows 8.1 Pro, and the IDE I am using is Eclipse Juno. This is the crash report:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: emulator-arm.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    543837aa
  Fault Module Name:    ig4icd32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.15.10.2555
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e973113
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 005612cc
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 84a0
  Additional Information 4: 84a09ea102a12ee665c500221db8c9d6
```

This happens with every version of Android, every device, from 128-1024MB RAM; I have added `libs` to PATH, have toggled GPU and snapshot, turned off cameras, edited `config.ini` file. None of these solutions have worked for me.

**UPDATE 1**: When running a VirtualBox OpenGL test, `VBoxTestOGL.exe` crashes with the same fatal module and exception code. Also, Genymotion `player.exe` crashes on startup, but VirtualBox emulator launches (but cannot user input touches without Genymotion `player.exe`.

**UPDATE 2**: Gingerbread AVD I made: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUXBY.png` Also, no info about the AVD in the DDMS console/logs in Eclipse Juno.

**UPDATE 3**: New Gingerbread AVD according to @ChuongPham 's specifications: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdtI7.png` but still no luck running the emulator. Also, logcat does not even connect to the emulator; it seems like the emulator is terminated before it connects to ADB: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZPc.png`

**UPDATE 4**: When running the AVD with the `-verbose` option, the emulator crashes after logging `emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support` with all emulated devices.

Comment: What JDK version are you using to run Android? And, how much RAM do you have on the Windows 8 computer?

Comment: Using JDK 8u25, 4GB RAM.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Android currently does *not* support JDK v8, you'll need JDK v7 (v7u67). So, to run Android:

- Download JDK v7u67 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). Note: Get the Windows x64 version for Windows 8.
- After JDK installation, open your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio, etc) and direct the IDE to use this new JDK. For example, in Eclipse select **Windows | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs** and select the JDK installed directory - not the Java Runtime (JRE) directory. The default JDK directory on a Windows computer will be something like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67". *Note: You can have multiple JDKs installed on a computer, but your IDE **must** use JDK v7.*

**IMPORTANT**: On Windows, specifying RAM option for an AVD greater than 1MB will not work. The RAM value has to be less than 1MB. Note: 1MB in Windows means 1,024 kilobytes.

**UPDATE 1:** If your AVD is not started normally, you can try the following commands (repeatedly) to force the ADB server to start:

- Type `adb kill-server`
- Then type `adb start-server`
- Then type `adb devices`

The last command will tell you whether your device is connected to ADB or not. The **ADB** executable is located at `/android-sdk/platform-tools` directory.

Also, change the ADB's default timeout to more than five seconds (5000 milliseconds), for example, 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds). In Eclipse, you can access the **ADB connection timeout** option by going to **Windows | Preferences | Android | DDMS**.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** If your AVD still crashed after trying the above fixes, then try this:

- For the AVD, change the **Device** option to use WVGA resolution (less than 1280x800) instead of WXGA. Then, click **OK** to save the changes.
- In Windows, open a command prompt and **Run as Administrator**.
- In the command prompt, navigate to `/android-sdk/tools/` directory.
- Then type **emulator -memory 512 -avd <avd_name>**. Note: Substitute **<avd_name>** with the actual name of the AVD you want to start.

Lastly, if it still doesn't work, then dump the Eclipse Juno + Android bundle and download Eclipse Kepler or Luna separately from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Then, download the Android SDK separately from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), and ADT [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) to build a new development environment to test AVD.

**BUG**: The issue you're facing could also be related to this unresolved [Issue 28601](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28601).

**UPDATE 3:**

If you get the **emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support** error, then try the following fixes:

- Add the path of OpenGLES drivers to your **System Variable**. You can access system variable via **Start | Control Panel | System | Advanced System Settings | Environment Variables | Path | Edit** and add **C:\Program Files\android-sdk\tools\lib** to the end of the **Variable Value** option and press OK to save.
- Update the nVidia drivers of your graphic card via **Windows Update**.
- Update the nVidia drivers of your graphic card via [nVidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk).

**BUG**: OpenGLES error could be related to [Issue 34233](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34233).

Comment: I tried with multiple RAM values (I also tried 1MB), after installing JDK 7 and adding it to my IDE. Still the same crash no matter what Android version I select. I disabled cameras, snapshot, and gpu, but the emulator still crashes.

Comment: Have you granted administrative permission for the `/android-sdk/` directory and subdirectories in your Windows 8 computer? Windows permission can sometimes interfere with applications running properly, Android included. It's one reason why I do most of my Android development on a Linux box and only a small part in Windows (if required).

Comment: I just now gave administrative permissions to ADT and all sub-directories within. Still no luck, from low-end to high end settings. Still the same crash code.

Comment: @LyricWulf: Post a screenshot of one of your AVDs and let me see how you set it up. Also, edit your post and include other info like what IDE is used, etc. The more info you provided, the more I have to narrow down the cause of the problem. Also check the DDMS Console in your IDE to see if any errors are listed when the AVD started booting up.

Comment: I added the requested information to the original post.

Comment: Change your **VM Heap** (vm.heapSize) option to at least **64** and change the **Skin** (skin.dynamic) option to **Skin with dynamic hardware controls**. Also, is your graphic card bought in the last three years or so? If yes, also enable the **Use Host GPU** option to allow the graphic card to render the AVD's UI. Don't bother about the **Snapshot** option - it's more troublesome than it's worth. Lastly, no logs in DDMS Console - that's weird! There should be at least some logs before the AVD crashes...

Comment: Also, see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#logcat) about getting logs from the shell/command prompt for an AVD if you don't get any logs from the IDE's Console.

Comment: Made a new AVD with new settings, and I toggled **Use Host GPU** with no luck, whether it was on or off. It seems like the emulator terminates before it can connect to ADB. See **UPDATE 3**.
P.S.: Thank you @ChuongPham for your continued support.

Comment: I have set the ADB timeout to 30 seconds, but still no luck in detecting the emulator with `adb devices`. The only error in the DDMS log is due to killing the ADB server: `[DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. I know that my ADB is fully functional because I use it with my phone, and it can detect it without any problems. The emulator still fails to start with the same crash code.

Comment: As previously stated, ADB and my drivers work fine with my **physical phone**. The problem is not with ADB. The problem is that the **emulator** will not start up on my computer.

Comment: Are your Android SDK and ADT on the same release version. For example, if you installed Android SDK v23.0.2, you **must** also have ADT v23.0.2 installed. Mismatch Android SDK and ADT versions have lead to many unforseen problems in the past.

Comment: I installed both at the same time from the ADT bundle zip from the Android website. Checked md5s, there is no error there.

Comment: @LyricWulf: Without a Windows 8.1 similar environment here to test and help you, I'm running out of options. However, I have editted my answer with **UPDATE 2** with some more suggestions.

Comment: Still crashes with your update 2. I do not think that the issue is related to the bug you posted with update 2, since the verbose logs of that issue show that the emulator gets past the point where mine crashes. See my **UPDATE4** for details. Maybe the verbose log will help us see what is wrong.

Comment: Editing PATH did not help, my graphics card isn't nVidia, I have an Intel integrated chipset. No driver updates via Windows update.

Comment: @LyricWulf: Try upgrading your graphic drivers for your graphic card, maybe motherboard too, if you have an integrated chipset onboard. Sorry, I'm just running out of ideas trying to help you solve this issue.

Comment: All drivers are up to date, according to Intel, HP, and Windows. This might just be some bug we can't fix without going too deep in code.

Comment: In that case, please log a bug with Google at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list. Maybe they know the cause and can fix this for you.

Comment: Will do. I am going to leave this question unresolved until there is a solution. Thanks again for your help.